# OrientDB import CSV is modifying my property name

Tags: csv, properties, import, character, orientdb

I'm no expert in OrientDB, and I'm having a problem with an odd character showing up in the command line. Oddly enough, it's in the name of my property. Because the name of the property is different, my queries are breaking.

For example, I can't execute

`SELECT * FROM Class WHERE Property = '%something%'`

because that Property doesn't exist. I would need to execute

`SELECT * FROM Class WHERE ?Property = '%something%'`

However, I don't know what that mystery character is. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

When I looked at that weird character in the raw JSON format through the web browser, it had a title of "\ufeff".

The property with the weird character was the first property in the .csv header. Since my text editor was set to "UTF-8" instead of "UTF-8 without BOM". As such, part of the metadata bled over into the first property. The result was that I wasn't able to select from that property or establish an edge to/from it.